# transporte de variavel entre paginas, php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Possuo uma página de login na qual após a entrada de usuário e senha ele é redirecionado para uma nova página.

De qual forma posso armazenar os dados desse usuário e disponibilizar nas próximas páginas?

Comment: Tem várias formas de fazer procure por sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é usando sessões. Você precisa colocar session_start() no começo de cada página onde você vai ativar a sessão. Aqui tem um exemplo simples:

Pagina inicial

```html
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["email"])){
 $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
 header("Location: minha_pagina.php");
 exit();
}
?>
```

Página seguinte:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["email"])){
 echo $_SESSION["email"];
}
?>
```

Aqui tem mais informações?

https://medium.com/weyes/trabalhando-e-manipulando-sess%C3%A3o-no-php-ece2d9bf9e31

Comment: Bins, cara deu certinho. muito obrigado ! :D